# Using states and props in React Native

Tags: react-native

Can I use a child components state in App.js? I mean, in a child component I have a variable for example i = 5 and I would like to use this in App.js. In App.js this.state.i shows 0.

Comment: Reactjs and React native are two different things.

Comment: Hi! I am currently using React Native. Sorry about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MuratKaragöz but they handle state and props the same

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic pattern in react so maybe just read through the official docs oder do some tutorials for getting started with react.

But to help you out on this you need to pass down a function to your child that sets the state in `<App/>`

So something like this:

App:

```
    this.state { i : 0 }

    updateState() {
        this.setState(i: i + 1); // or whatever
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                 <Child updateState={this.updateState} />
            </>
    ....
```

Child:

```
<div onClick={props.updateState}>Click me</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response, well, in child component I don't want onClick. I set a value of a variable in child component and I would like to read this value from its parent component in App.js, but no onClick involved.

Comment: This code is considered to be pseudo code and could help you guide you in the right direction - if you use click or not does not really matter, as you could always just call the props.updateState() function in your child

Comment: No offense, but I do not want to pass down a value to child and later modify its value in parent. I have a variable in child component and I would like to use it in parent component. I guess that your code does not like this. Thank you anyway! Thanks for the props.updateState() that is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

On app.js do this;

```
constructor(props) {
this.updateI=this.updateI.bind(this)
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       i:0
    }
}

        updateI(i){
         this.setState({i})
    }

    render() {
            return (
                <View >
                        <Child updateI={this.updateI}/>
                </View>
            )
        }
```

on your child do this:

```
this.props.updateI(5);
```